# class.getResource unconsistant behavior in-Eclipse vs in-jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, resources

I'm testing how to express paths to resource files. I get different results between Eclipse and command line with a jar.

**Could you help me understand why there are differences?**

I've two resource files:

- one is in the class package, at the same level than the class file.
- one is outside the class package, at the same level than the package.

Eclipse. This does work:

```
package com.example.mypackage;

/*    FileIO (project)
 *      |
 *      +---- src (source folder)
 *             |
 *             +---- com.example.mypackage (package)
 *             |              |
 *             |              +---- TestRes.java (class)
 *             |              |
 *             |              +---- users (resource file 1)
 *             |
 *             +---- test.txt (resource file 2)
 */

public class TestRes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Some resource names (relative, absolute)
        String[][] res = {
            { "users"            , "/com/example/mypackage/users" },
            { "../../../test.txt", "/test.txt" },
            { "."                , "/com/example/mypackage/" }
        };

        // Get resource URL
        String f = "Relative: %s\nAbsolute: %s\nURL: %s (%s)\n\n";
        for (String[] r : res) {
            String n0 = r[0];
            String n1 = r[1];
            try {
                String url0 = TestRes.class.getResource(n0).getPath();
                String url1 = TestRes.class.getResource(n1).getPath();
                System.out.printf(f, n0, n1, url0, (url0.equals(url1)));
            }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Relative: users
Absolute: /com/example/mypackage/users
URL: /C:/Users/User/workspace/FileIO/bin/com/example/mypackage/users (true)

Relative: ../../../test.txt
Absolute: /test.txt
URL: /C:/Users/User/workspace/FileIO/bin/test.txt (true)

Relative: .
Absolute: /com/example/mypackage/
URL: /C:/Users/User/workspace/FileIO/bin/com/example/mypackage/ (true)
```

But when I export the project to a jar (right-click on FileIO, then `export`), and run the jar with `java.exe` at the command line, then `class.getResource()` returns `null` when trying to processing the second case (`"../../../test.txt"`) and third case (`"."`).

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>java -jar TestRes.jar
Relative: users
Absolute: /com/example/mypackage/users
URL: file:/C:/Users/User/Desktop/TestRes.jar!/com/example/mypackage/users (true)

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.mypackage.TestRes.main(TestRes.java:31)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.mypackage.TestRes.main(TestRes.java:31)
```

I checked the structure of the jar:

- `test.txt` is at the root of the jar
- there are 3 additional files at the root (classpath, project, and manifest)
- `TestRes.class` and users are in `com\example\mypackage` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running from Eclipse, the IDE is simulating the runtime class loader behavior by mapping to basic file system operations over src and bin folders. The simulated behavior may not be an exact match for the real runtime behavior in all the corner cases. In this particular case, it looks like the simulator is not preventing the use of paths not supported at runtime.

Comment: Indeed, was not thinking about that. Digging into the doc, I see that the class loader delegates to the parent class loader, if any, or calls getBootstrapResource instead. If this step cannot find the resource, then the class loader calls the findResource method which by default returns no result (must be implemented by derived class). As getBootstrapResource is not open source, I don't know exactly where the resources may be stored. Do you have a link to the resource location constraints? Thanks.

Comment: @mins: `com/example/mypackage/users` is a classpath resource. It's not the file called `users` in the directory called `mypackage`. So, don't try to read it as a file in the file system. As you have seen from your experiment, it's not going to work always, specially when you know that you are going to create an archive file like jar, war, ...

Comment: The javadoc for Class.getResource() lays out the only two types of paths that are supported... From the root of the package tree or from the current package. No provisions for parent navs or other stuff you are trying. These aren't file system paths. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung: Thanks. I'm not sure I get your point exactly. My understanding is that the structure of the resource name can be mapped to folders and a file in the file system or, by extension, in the jar, at least under Windows. Correct me if this is not valid in contexts other than mine. I have read "users" content using "TestRes.class.getResourceAsStream(r[1])" both in Eclipse and in the jar.

Comment: @mins: `TestRes.class.getResourceAsStream(r[1])` is the correct way to read any classpath resource. *My understanding is that the structure of the resource name can be mapped to folders and a file in the file system ...* That's the misunderstanding that I was trying to point you to. Take e.g. `C:/Users/User/Desktop/TestRes.jar!/com/example/mypackage/users`, that doesn't exist on your actual file system. There won't be any directory called `TestRes.jar!` in your file system.